# Blowfish vs. Twofish regarding power consumption

Tags: implementation, reference-request, blowfish, twofish

If I wanted to use Blowfish or Twofish to provide security on a device where power consumption is crucial. Regarding power consumption, which one would win?

Generally, which algorithms are known to consume the least energy and why? Which parameters should be considered the most? How much research is done regarding power consumption of cryptographic algorithms?

Comment: Cryptographic primitive performance is highly dependent on the implemented platform, Keccak for example, will obliterate Blake in hardware design, but the exact opposite is the case on an x64 CPU

Comment: Is memory particularly limited? And what CPU architecture are you using? Twofish's larger block size is very likely to guarantee fewer cycles per byte, and it is fairly well-optimized for low-end processors.